# Find Matrix for Linear Transformation Given Criteria

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, education

Suppose the linear transformation $T$ does the following:

- maps $R^2$ to the plane given by $x-2y+3z=0$,
- preserves angles and distances, and
- maps $(2,4)$ to $(-3\sqrt{2},0,\sqrt{2})$.

I have two questions. First, how might we construct a matrix for $T$? I'm sure that there are multiple ways to do this. Is there a "standard" way that would make sense to someone studying linear algebra for this first time?

Second, is $T$ unique? If not, what additional criteria would make it unique?

This is not a homework question. I am a high school teacher trying to create a challenge problem for some advanced students. Appreciate any responses.

Comment: First of all, kudos to you for teaching linear algebra in highschool; I only learnt it in my second year of college. Any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be decomposed as a linear sum of the unit vectors along the axes (basis vectors). So if these vectors map to the plane, then all $\mathbb{R}^2$ vectors will also map. I think $|T|=1$ preserves distances (though not completely sure).

Comment: From an algebraic perspective, one could view $T$ as a collection of 9 unknowns and solve for them using equations derived from the given criteria. Though this may be an inefficient approach, and I think more criteria would be required for uniqueness, though I'm not sure how much.

Comment: So you want $T$ to map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$? I think the most complicated part is the preserving angles and distances part. I would at first include $\mathbb{R}$^2 into $\mathbb{R}^3$ in an obvious way and then compose by an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

We can look at this transformation as a rotation that has two conditions:

- The image of $u_1=[0, 0, 1]^T$ is $v_1 =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}}[1, -2, 3]^T $
- The image of $u_2=[2, 4, 0]^T$ is $v_2=[-3 \sqrt{2}, 0, \sqrt{2}]^T $

From these two pairs, we can generate a third pair as follows:

- The image of $u_1 \times u_2$ is $v_1 \times v_2$

Hence, we now have the following matrix equation

$ [v_1, v_2, v_3] = R [u_1, u_2, u_3] $

so that

$ R = [v_1, v_2, v_3] [u_1, u_2, u_3]^{-1} $

By writing a small code to implement this, you get

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} -0.27308 && -0.92412 && 0.267261 \\
0.755929 && -0.37796 && -0.53452 \\ 0.594979 && 0.056064 && 0.801784 \end{bmatrix} $

The linear transformatin matrix from $\mathbb{R}^2 $ to $\mathbb{R}^3 $ is the first two columns of $R$, hence,

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -0.27308 && -0.92412 \\
0.755929 && -0.37796  \\ 0.594979 && 0.056064 \end{bmatrix} $

If we now repeat the above steps, but with the image of $u_1$ being $-v_1$, then the rotation matrix will be

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} -0.57545 && -0.77294 && -0.26726 \\ -0.75593 && 0.377964 && 0.534522 \\ -0.31214 && 0.509621 && -0.80178 \end{bmatrix} $

So that the transformation matrix is the first two columns and this gives us

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -0.57545 && -0.77294 \\ -0.75593 && 0.377964  \\ -0.31214 && 0.509621  \end{bmatrix} $